# What is the solution to poissons equation with a point source?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, poissons-equation

I am currently trying to solve the following PDE using various numerical methods - direct and iterative.

$$
\nabla ^2 u = \rho
$$

where $u = u(x,y)$ and $\rho(0.5,0.5) = 2$ (zero elsewhere). The domain is $0<x,y<1$ and $u = 0$ on the boundaries.

I am fairly sure that I have written my numerical algorithms correctly, however I do not have the knowledge to interpret the output in relation to what the "true" solution is.

I have found that for all grids the discretized laplacian at (0.5,0.5) is equal to two within floating point precision - this is what I expect should be the case. My main issue is that I do not witness convergence in any sense that I understand, as the grid spacing decreases the values of the solution just get smaller and smaller. It seems to me that if I could solve on a grid with infinitely small spacing (this is my understanding of what the "true" solution is?) then I would just have a constant solution that takes the value zero at all points in the domain??

I would appreciate any answer that could explain what the analytical solution to this PDE is and any insight into what behaviour I should look for in terms of convergence for my numerical methods - I am clear how to describe the convergence of the iterative methods but not the convergence with respect to the "true" solution of the PDE. My gut instinct is that this particular problem is not well behaved in some sense!!

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this supposed to be a *Dirac* point source with weight 2, or a density of 2 at just one point? In the second case the right hand side doesn't do anything, so you should get a function which is almost exactly zero over the whole domain when the mesh size is small.

Comment: The distinction between the two eludes me...the problem is not described in terms of diracs just a function that takes value of 2 at a single point...

Comment: Then it is probably not a Dirac source and is indeed intended to be a density of 2 at the point. A Dirac source would correspond to a *mass* of size 2 at 0.

Comment: Note that this means that you're essentially working with a total mass of zero (a finite density at a single point amounts to no mass), which is why you should expect the potential to overall be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numerical methods will generally converge to a weak solution, which will also be a strong solution if one exists. Here the weak solution is the zero function, and there is no strong solution (which should be unsurprising, since the forcing on the right side is not continuous). You can check that the weak solution is the zero function quite easily, because when you multiply by any test function, the right side will integrate to zero (since it is only nonzero at one point), so the left side should also integrate to zero as well.

Comment: +1, although the main obstruction to a strong solution here isn't the discontinuity, but the fact that the point has measure zero.

Comment: @user7530 I do not claim that "the forcing is discontinuous so there is no strong solution" holds. I'm merely saying that we shouldn't be surprised to see no strong solution when we apply a discontinuous forcing. Sometimes we see one anyway, however, you're right.

Comment: That answer makes partial sense to me, and certainly agrees with the numerical solutions I have obtained. However the zero functions second derivative at (0.5,0.5) is not equal to 2 (surely it is equal to 0) so how can that be the solution to this particular problem???

Comment: @JoshGreenhalgh This is the distinction between "strong" and "weak" solutions. A strong solution will have the smoothness required by the equation and will satisfy the equation at each point. A weak solution will only satisfy the equation "on average". Here you can't have a function whose second derivative is nonzero at exactly one point, so the weak solution is the zero function and no strong solution exists.

Comment: @JoshGreenhalgh I'll repeat my previous comment that may give some physical intuition. Poisson's equation can among other things provide the gravitational potential given the density of mass. When you put a finite density at one point, the total mass adds up to zero. So you should expect that the "solution" (whatever that means) should not care about the condition in the interior, since there is no mass in the interior.

Comment: Thanks...that makes perfect sense to me now! I really appreciate the answer.